# Unix "cp -p". Can I preserve attributes selectively?

Tags: macos, permissions, cp

I'd like to copy the modification and access times, but not the user ID. If I use

```
cp -p source target
```

It will copy everything.

I'm trying to copy files to a different user but keep the original dates intact.

Answer (score 6):

From the `cp` manual of `GNU coreutils`:

> `-p`     same as `--preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps`

So, you are looking for

```
cp --preserve=mode,timestamps source target
```

But if you use some non-GNU operating system, you might not be able to use these long option with `cp`. In that case, you can give `rsync` a try, where you can specify in details which attributes should be preserved (search the man page for "preserve"):

```
    -H, --hard-links            preserve hard links
    -p, --perms                 preserve permissions
    -E, --executability         preserve executability
    -A, --acls                  preserve ACLs (implies -p)
    -X, --xattrs                preserve extended attributes
    -o, --owner                 preserve owner (super-user only)
    -g, --group                 preserve group
        --devices               preserve device files (super-user only)
        --specials              preserve special files
    -t, --times                 preserve modification times
```

So, to resemble the `cp` command above, use something like

```
rsync -pEt source target
```

To test the command beforehand, you can initiate a "dry-run" with `-n`. Add also the verbose parameter `-v` to see what's going on:

```
rsync -nv -pEt source target
```

However, I'm not sure, if the *access* time will be copied, too.

Comment: Makes sense, but I'm (noobishly) not sure how to use the long options. I've been trying to test with something safer than cp ("ls --all") but I get an "illegal option" error.

Comment: Are you using some non-GNU Un*x system? BSD for example? Honestly, I didn't paid too much attention to the flags in the question, so my answer applies to `cp` from the GNU coreutils. `ls --all` works there, too.

Comment: I'm on a Mac using the Terminal application.

Comment: Then, I think, your `cp` doesn't offer long options. I'll add an alternative possibility with `rsync`, perhaps that's an option for you.

Comment: Or you could use one of the FOSS package managers for Mac OS and install GNU cp.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the ditto command preserves dates.

> ditto src target

Comment: This is the only solution that worked properly for me to preserve mtimes.  When using `cp -p...`, or `cp -p -r...`, for some unknown reason, 4 out of 10 files preserved their mtime as expected, but the other 6 showed up with the copy time as the new mtime.